# Access Queue from two separate Threads in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

So my goal is to measure the performance of a *Streaming Engine*. It's basically a library to which i can send data-packages. The idea to measure this is to generate data, put it into a Queue and let the *Streaming Engine* grab the data and process it.

I thought of implementing it like this: The *Data Generator* runs in a thread and generates data packages in an endless loop with a certain `Thread.sleep(X)` at the end. When doing the tests the idea is to minimize tis `Thread.sleep(X)` to see if this has an impact on the *Streaming Engine's* performance. The *Data Generator* writes the created packages into a queue, that is, a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, which at the same time is a Singleton.

In another thread I instantiate the *Streaming Engine* which continuously removes the packages from the queue by doing `queue.remove()`. This is done in an endlees loop without any sleeping, because it should just be done as fast as possible.

In a first try to implement this I ran into a problem. It seems as if the *Data Generator* is not able to put the packages into the Queue as it should be. It is doing that too slow. My suspicion is that the endless loop of the *Streaming Engine* thread is eating up all the resources and therefore slows down everything else.

I would be happy about how to approach this issue or other design patterns, which could solve this issue elegantly.

the requirements are: 2 threads which run in parallel basically. one is putting data into a queue. the other one is reading/removing from the queue. and i want to measure the size of the queue regularly in order to know if the engine which is reading/removing from the queue is fast enough to process the generated packages.

Comment: You will probably want to use some sort of Blocking (Queue/Deque), so that the remove/take only happens when there is actually an element available.

Comment: What is your question? I see something about Data Generator being too slow, but no information that could help say something about that. The rest seems to be a lot of information but what are you asking, specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a BlockingQueue, for example [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), you can initialize these to a certain size, so the number of items queued will never exceed a certain number, as per this example:

```
// create queue, max size 100
final ArrayBlockingQueue<String> strings = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);
final String stop = "STOP";

// start producing
Runnable producer = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        strings.put(Integer.toHexString(i));
      }
      strings.put(stop);
    } catch(InterruptedException ignore) {
    }
  }
};

Thread producerThread = new Thread(producer);
producerThread.start();

// start monitoring
Runnable monitor = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (true){
        System.out.println("Queue size: " + strings.size());
        Thread.sleep(5);
      }
    } catch(InterruptedException ignore) {
    }
  }
};
Thread monitorThread = new Thread(monitor);
monitorThread.start();

// start consuming
Runnable consumer = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // infinite look, will interrupt thread when complete
    try {
      while(true) {
        String value = strings.take();
        if(value.equals(stop)){
          return;
        }
        System.out.println(value);
      }
    } catch(InterruptedException ignore) {
    }
  }
};

Thread consumerThread = new Thread(consumer);
consumerThread.start();

// wait for producer to finish
producerThread.join();
consumerThread.join();

// interrupt consumer and monitor
monitorThread.interrupt();
```

You could also have third thread monitoring the size of the queue, to give you an idea of which thread is outpacing the other.

Also, you can used the timed put method and the timed or untimed offer methods, which will give you more control of what to do if the queue if full or empty. In the above example execution will stop until there is space for the next element or if there are no further elements in the queue.

Comment: thanks, that looks promising. one question regarding the third thread for monitoring the size of the queue: this would just be implemented as a new thread which, in a while(true) loop, will sysout the size of the queue right?

Comment: I have added the monitor `Thread` to clarify. You probably want some measure of sleep in that monitorThread. Otherwise it will start competing with your producer and consumer threads for CPU.

Comment: thanks for your helpful answers. your example works for me in a plain java project. however, i am implementing a webapp, which is deployed via tomcat. when i run the project after on tomcat, this code does not work, even though i exactly do as you suggest. i use an unbounded LinkedBlockingQueue, which is accessible as a singleton. the code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/tZvwASUz

the output looks like this: http://pastebin.com/Zxz3bpsy
between the 4th and 5th package there should be only 1000ms of sleep (line 12+13). However it takes 8sec (time diff between line 12 and 13). why the lag?

Comment: Sorry - can't really help much with that without knowing more of the rest of the code. I am not familiar with tomcat. Might there be something that is holding up your producer or consumer threads? Or - as you're using an unbounded queue, are you running out of memory?

Comment: thanks for your answer again. the problem has something to do with my code, because if i run your code in the webapp, it also works fine. i guess i will have to figure out, what's wrong with my code. basically it's doing the same.

Comment: Ok, might it be the fact that you said you were using an unbounded queue? Try setting a restriction on that.

Comment: finally found the bug. in the consumer i did something like this: `if (queue.size > 0) then queue.take(); else sysout("queue is empty")` and this else clause somehow was causing all of the trouble. if i remove it, then everything works fine. however, i want to know, when the queue is 0. is it possible to measure this inside the consumer-thread?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62823/discussion-between-beta-and-peterk).